# How to replace an element in a JSON file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, json

I need to replace the following text:

```
"name":["abc1234"], age:"24"
```

with

```
"name": "abc1234", age: "24"
```

Comment: post the full json content OR a testable fragment

Comment: what's the rule of replacement? should it cut the digits from existing value `abc1234` OR just replace with static string `abc`? Post a valid object notation

Comment: I don't see why this question got these many upvotes.. no code/research effort shown, only one sample line given without explanation.. should entire line be matched? only `"name":[...]` and so on...

Comment: The document in the question is not a JSON document. It is missing enclosing curly braces, and the `age` key is not quoted.

Answer (score 13):

If I understand correctly, you want do replace the "name" list by its first element. If this is the case try a Json processor:

```
jq '.name=.name[0]' ex.json
```

(adaptations to the unpost full example may be needed)

Answer (score 7):

The general answer is

```
man 7 regex
```

but specifically

```
sed -E 's/"name":\["abc1234"\], age:"24" /"name": "abc1234", age:"24"/g' file > new
```

or

```
sed -E 's/"name" *: *\["([^"]+)"\], *age *: *"([0-9]+)"/"name": "\1", age:"\2"/g' file > new
grep -E '"name" *: *\[' new
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be using the [Python JSON module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21035861/5794048). Here's a simple example:

- `in.json`

  ```json
  { "name":["abc1234"], "age":"24" }
  ```
- `replaceInJson.py`

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/python3

  import json

  with open("in.json", "r") as f:
      data = json.load(f)
      print("Before:", data)
      data["name"] = data["name"][0]
      print("After: ", data)
  ```
- Output

  ```json
  Before: {'name': ['abc1234'], 'age': '24'}
  After:  {'name': 'abc1234', 'age': '24'}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the JSON document is well-formed and that the two keys `name` and `age` are top-level keys, as in

```json
{
   "name": [ "abc1234" ],
   "age": "24"
}
```

... then we may use `jq` to replace the value of the `name` key with the first element of the array:

```bash
$ jq '.name |= first' file
{
  "name": "abc1234",
  "age": "24"
}
```

If the input is an array of similar elements, as in

```json
[
   {
      "age": "24",
      "name": [ "abc1234" ]
   },
   {
      "age": "24",
      "name": [ "abc1234" ]
   },
   {
      "age": "24",
      "name": [ "abc1234" ]
   },
   {
      "age": "24",
      "name": [ "abc1234" ]
   }
]
```

Then `map` the operation to each element:

```bash
$ jq 'map(.name |= first)' file
[
  {
    "name": "abc1234",
    "age": "24"
  },
  {
    "name": "abc1234",
    "age": "24"
  },
  {
    "name": "abc1234",
    "age": "24"
  },
  {
    "name": "abc1234",
    "age": "24"
  }
]
```