# how do I fix a jq expression returning Invalid path expression error?

Tags: jq

I have a package.json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "my service",
  "license": "none",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mycompany/mypackage": "1.1.1"
  }
}
```

I want to update the @mycompany/mypackage version to "1.2.1".  I found articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292243/how-to-modify-a-keys-value-in-a-json-file-from-command-line) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411844/how-to-replace-an-element-in-a-json-file) suggesting jq.

When I run my jq command `jq -r '"dependencies.@mycompany/mypackage" |= "1.2.1"' package.json`, I get this error: `jq: error (at temp.json:13): Invalid path expression with result "dependencies.@mycompany/m...`

From what I can tell the path is correct when I used [jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/pAPLUBIUiF).

Does anyone have a suggestion what is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're pretty close. You do need to quote the `@mycompany/mypackage` key, because both the `@` and `/` are special characters, but you have to quote it separately, not as part of the whole filter. Also you need a leading `.` to query the root object. This should work:

```
$ jq -r '.dependencies."@mycompany/mypackage" |= "1.2.1"' package.json
{
  "name": "service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "my service",
  "license": "none",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mycompany/mypackage": "1.2.1"
  }
}
```